# Any way to get location address without internet connection availability from android device

Tags: android, gps

I`m developing an attendance application there I want track employee with internet or without internet when employee phone has no internet connection I can get latitude and longitude but I want a complete address from latitude and longitude without an internet connection

I already try Geocoder but Geocoder work with internet and I need a solution that works without internet

```
 Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(activity.getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());

        latitude = Double.parseDouble(params[0]);
        longitude = Double.parseDouble(params[1]);

        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "LATITUDE LONGITUDE " + latitude + longitude);
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(params[0]), Double.parseDouble(params[1]), 1);
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            }
            return address;
```

I expect the address without an internet connection

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: You can build your own offline address database, which means you have to write each address + it's location in your database, and store it offline on your device. Depending on which range of addresses you want to check, it might take 10 or 100 GB space to store all the data.

Comment: You can setup a server with in ternet connection and communicate with the server via SMS messages.